# Combining all combinations of data from three columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a few columns of data that I would like to combine, and get each unique combination.

Concatenating across a row or set list is easy enough, but I would rather not have to enter each possible permutation...that would be a waste of time.

So how can I get excel to list out each possible combination of columns a, b and c?  (I do not want to combine the options within each column.

So for example if I start with "ado" I would like ado-ar-en, ado-r-en, ado-an-en, ado-n-en...well you get the idea its a long list.

[image]

Comment: This comment won't help with Excel, but there is an open-source wordlist generator for Linux called "crunch" that will do this.

Comment: The first idea that came to mind was overly complicated and involved random number generation to get me a three cell set that would have Ax, Bx, and Cx.  But then I couldn't figure out how to convert the Ax text to a cell value when concatenating (it wasn't real effective...at all)

Comment: You keep using the term "random".  Are you looking for some number of random combinations, all possible combinations, or all possible combinations in random order?

Comment: @Raystafarian - could you post an answer illustrating your suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780016/vba-write-all-possible-combinations-of-4-columns-of-data

Comment: That question did the trick, @Raystafarian do you want to put that in an answer so I can accept or should we just close this question?

Comment: Posted an answer as community wiki @excelll

Comment: @Raystafarian Ah I just happened to see this in the review queue. Thanks. Your ping missed me because you have one to few L's.

Comment: @Excellll ah, whoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Source from [Excellll](https://superuser.com/users/76571/excellll) on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729967/macro-to-make-all-possible-combinations-of-data-in-various-columns-in-excel-shee/5731496#5731496). His code.

The easiest way would be to take the lists, independently, and store them in an array. Then use the arrays to output all possible combinations. This code will output in 3 different columns, but you can concatenate if you need them in a single cell

```
Sub combinations()

Dim c1() As Variant
Dim c2() As Variant
Dim c3() As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set col2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
Set col3 = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))

c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3

Set out1 = Range("E2", Range("G2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3)))
out = out1

j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            out(m, 1) = c1(j, 1)
            out(m, 2) = c2(k, 1)
            out(m, 3) = c3(l, 1)
            m = m + 1
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        l = 1
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = 1
    j = j + 1
Loop


out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, I do not have Excel available (using LibreOffice at home, this won't work in LibreOffice).

IF IT WORKS ;-) it should/does:
Assumes "ad" is in cell A1 and the rest just beside it.
Fill in D1 and down with combined results as long as the 'current' cell isn't an empty cell in each of A, B, and C columns.

```
sub list_gen

  a=1
  d=1
  while Worksheets(1).Cells(a,1).Text<>""
    astr=Worksheets(1).Cells(a,1).text
    b=1
    while Worksheets(1).Cells(b,2).text<>""
      bstr=Worksheets(1).Cells(b,2).text
      c=1
      while Worksheets(1).Cells(c,3).text<>""
        cstr=Worksheets(1).Cells(c,3).text
        c=c+1
        Worksheets(1).Cells(d,4).text=astr+"-"+bstr+"-"+cstr
        d=d+1
       wend 
       b=b+1
    wend  
    a=a+1
  wend 

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a "three dimensional" table to capture all of the combinations.  Your lists have 11, 11, and 5 entries so create five 11x11 tables.  Each of the five will contain combinations involving one of the entries in your third column.  The cells in each table will reflect the combination of one item from your first column and one from your second.

Let's assume the data you show is in `A1:C11`.  Create the first table starting in `A15`.  We'll label the rows and columns of the table with index numbers that will be used to look up the cells for each entry in the table.  So table 1 would be set up like this:

```
         [A]  [B]  [C]  [D]  [E]  [F]  [G]  [H]  [I]  [J]  [K]  [L]
    [15]       0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
    [16]  0
    [17]  1
    [18]  2
    [19]  3
    [20]  4
    [21]  5
    [22]  6
    [23]  7
    [24]  8
    [25]  9
    [26] 10
```

The formula in `B16` would be:

```
    =OFFSET($A$1,$A16,0,)&OFFSET($B$1,B$15,0,)&$C$1
```

Copy this to fill all the cells in the table.  The first expression anchors the list in column A and picks the entry corresponding with the row label for the table (the first row has an offset of zero, so it refers to the first entry in the list).  The second expression anchors the list in column B and picks the entry corresponding to the column label.  The third expression uses the first value in the column C list for all entries in the first table.  The dollar signs in the expressions anchor the formulas to the table's row and column labels so you can copy the formula to fill the table and each cell will refer to the right labels.  The ampersands concatenate the three values.  If you want to have a delimiter between the values, like the hyphen you show, use this in place of the ampersands in the formula:

```
    &"-"&
```

So `B16` will show `adaren` or `ad-ar-en`.  `C16` will show `adren` or `ad-r-en`.  `B17` will show `adoaren` or `ado-ar-en`.

Create the other tables exactly the same way beside or below the first table, where it is convenient.  When you enter the formula for the first cell, point to the row and column labels in that table.  For example, if the second table starts below the first table in, say, `A30`, the first table cell will be `B31`.  The first expression in that formula would use `$A31` instead of `$A16`, and `B$30` instead of `B$15`.  The last expression in the second table will be `$C$2` instead of `$C$1`.  In the third table, it will be `$C$3`, and so on.

The five tables will contain all combinations of your list entries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the lists something like the following...run the macro and you'll have all your possible permutations in the format you specified

```
List_A  List_B  List_C  
A1      B1      C1      
A2      B2      C2      
A3  

    Sub RandomCombo()

    ListA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value) 'data starts in 2nd row
    ListB = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value) 'data starts in 2nd row
    ListC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Value) 'data starts in 2nd row

    counter = 2

    For i = 1 To UBound(ListA)
        For j = 1 To UBound(ListB)
            For k = 1 To UBound(ListC)
                Cells(counter, 4) = ListA(i) & "-" & ListB(j) & "-" & ListC(k)
                counter = counter + 1
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    End Sub
```